# How to view the calibrated real-time video in the .exe?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pyinstaller

I have a question for calibration of real-time video during the project.

Development Environment:
python 3.8 64bit
window
visual studio code

While showing real-time video on the screen through opencv, I realized that calibration was needed on the camera screen. So, calibration was successful through many searches. When I run it in 'vusual studio code' it works fine. But after creating the .exe via pyinstaller, the camera does not open. No error occurs. So I don't know any more. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Saved 'mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs' as 'calibration.npz' in the same path as the code. After that, I loaded it through the code below.

```
h,w = frame.shape[:2]  
with np.load('calibration.npz') as X:
    mtx, dist, _ , _ = [X[i] for i in ('mtx','dist','rvecs','tvecs')]
newcameramtx, roi = cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx, dist, (w, h), 0)
mapx, mapy = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx,(w, h), 5)

            
dst = cv2.remap(frame, mapx, mapy, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
global dst_final       
x, y, w, h = roi
dst_final=dst[y:y+h, x:x+w]
```

'calibration.npz' save code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import glob

CHECKERBOARD = (6,9)
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

objpoints = []
imgpoints = [] 


objp = np.zeros((1, CHECKERBOARD[0] * CHECKERBOARD[1], 3), np.float32)
objp[0,:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:CHECKERBOARD[0], 0:CHECKERBOARD[1]].T.reshape(-1, 2)*26  #*26 = 26mm(chekerboard size(mm))
prev_img_shape = None

images = glob.glob('C:\\Users\\MyPc\\KHS\\test2\\*.jpg')
for fname in images:
    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, CHECKERBOARD, cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK + cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE)
    
    if ret == True:
        objpoints.append(objp)
        corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11,11),(-1,-1), criteria)
        
        imgpoints.append(corners2)

        img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, CHECKERBOARD, corners2, ret)
    
    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

h,w = img.shape[:2]


ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)
newcameramtx, roi = cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx, dist, (w, h), 0)
mapx, mapy = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx,(w, h), 5)
dst = cv2.remap(img, mapx, mapy, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    
x, y, w, h = roi
dst=dst[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv2.imshow('num', dst)
cv2.imshow('ori', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

np.savez_compressed('calibration.npz',ret=ret,mtx=mtx,dist=dist,rvecs=rvecs,tvecs=tvecs)
```

When creating the .exe, I ran the following code:

```
pyinstaller -w --ico=myico.ico --add-data *.png;. ABC.py
```

In the .exe before calibration, the real-time video appeared on the screen, but in the .exe created after calibration, the real-time video does not appear on the screen and there are no other errors.

Any advice would be much appreciated. Please advise.

Comment: did you run .exe in console/terminal to see errors? Did you use `print()` to debug code and see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables?

Comment: do you add `*.png` but in code I see `*.jpg` ? Which format do you use?

Comment: do you know how `pyinstaller` works? It creates self-extracting .zip file with extension .exe and when you run it then it create temporary file and it extract files to this folder. If you use hardcoded path `C:\\Users\\MyPc\\KHS\\test2\\` then it may not find images which you added to file because they are in temporary folder - so it may not find it

Comment: @furas  OMG,,, I think it's because I didn't do `* .jpg`. I didn't think about `* .jpg` at all because all the other images are `* .png`. I also have to learn more about the path and the pyinstaller. Thank you. I'm really thankful to you.